# How to create view cache by RGB565?

Tags: android, caching, view

android 2.2, the default view cache is ARGB_8888,
How to create view's cache by RGB565?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to simply drop the least-significant bits.

Ie.
NewR = R >> 3;
NewG = G >> 2;
NewB = B >> 3;

However, I suppose a more thorough method might include some form of dithering, to minimise banding.

Comment: However AFAIK you wont be able to convert it to a view (if thats what you want)

Comment: But I want to directly create cache for view by RGB_565.
View.java -> buildDrawingCache()
In this module,the cache can be set to ARGB_8888 or RGB_565.